# Extra spaces in shell script inserting ''wc -c'' output into strings

Tags: linux, bash

I have an issue whenever I run this script. It gets the right word count of the file, but whenever I run it in the terminal it has unwanted spacing.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
char=$(cat $1 | wc -c)
echo "This file has $char characters in it."
nolines=$(cat $1 | tr -d "\n" | wc -c)
echo "This file has $nolines characters not counting the new line."
emptyline=$(grep -cv '\S' $1) echo "This file has $emptyline empty lines."
alphachar=$(tr -cd '[:alpha:]' < $1 | wc -c)
echo "This file has $alphachar alphanumeric characters."
```

Using a file with this in it called `example_file` (this is the file under this, or the content of the file):

```
This is the first line
This is the second
This has the symbols @#$

there was just an empty line.
```

So whenever I run my script like `~/script.sh example_file` it gives an output of

```
This file has        93 characters in it.
This file has        88 characters not counting the new line.
This file has 1 empty lines.
This file has        70 alphanumeric characters.
```

I was expecting for the output to have no spacing in between.

Comment: Note that `grep` is not guaranteed to understand that `\S` means `[^[:space:]]` -- POSIX only requires it to understand BRE and ERE regex syntax forms, certainly not PCRE.

Comment: I might have gotten the code block for `example_file` wrong, if there's supposed to be an empty line in it, please [edit] the question.

Comment: Also, `cat $1 |` is a slower and buggier way of writing `<"$1"` (slower because it starts a separate `/bin/cat` executable and forces the thing on the right-hand side to read from a FIFO instead of direct from the input file; buggier because it can't handle filenames with spaces). Consider making a habit of doing the latter.

Comment: Look at the output of `wc -c`. Does it have extra spaces? If so, it's reasonable to expect your variables to themselves have those spaces.

Comment: (btw, are you sure you're really on Linux? I see extra spaces in the output from BSD `wc`, but not from a GNU coreutils one; the latter is way more popular on Linux).

Comment: What do you mean by _whenever I run it in the terminal_. Run **what** exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `wc` is (sometimes) allowed to write spaces before the numeric result.

Consider the following behavior, seen on MacOS:

```
$ /usr/bin/wc -c <<<"hello" | xxd
00000000: 2020 2020 2020 2036 0a                          6.
```

Those `20`s are all spaces (the `0a` is the trailing newline, the `36` is the number 6); they're there because [the POSIX standard for `wc`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/wc.html) specifies that `-c` suppresses printing *numbers* except for the requested (byte-count) one; but it doesn't suppress printing *spaces*.

The behavior of this version of `wc` arguably violates the current version of the POSIX standard, which specifies that leading spaces should be suppressed when no filename is passed to `wc` as an argument; current GNU coreutils `wc` does not behave as the question describes.

Regardless, though, to turn it off you can just suppress whitespace using a [parameter expansion](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) such as `${char//[[:space:]]/}`, or an arithmetic context, `$((char))`:

```
char=$(wc -c <"$1")
echo "This file has $((char)) characters in it."
```

Comment: Maybe also mention the benefits of avoiding the [useless `cat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat)

Comment: Maybe also explain the benefits of `printf` rather than `echo`: `printf 'This file has %d characters in it.\n' "$(wc -c <"$1")"`. Or an arithmetic casting: `char=$(("$(wc -c <"$1")"+0))`

Comment: @LéaGris: or an integer declaration: `declare -i char=$(cat $1 | wc -c)`.

Comment: @LéaGris, an arithmetic context is a great idea, thank you. Where is the `+0` necessary?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy the `+0` is not necessary. My brain farted in a rush probably.